# How to update rows of a table using another table SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to update a column value in table called `test1` with column values from another table `test2` provided the columns `provisionid, categoryid, differencetype` are same.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t1
    SET SomeColumn = t2.SomeColumn
    FROM test1 t1
        INNER JOIN test2 t2
            ON t1.provisionid = t2.provisionid
                AND t1.categoryid = t2.categoryid
                AND t1.differencetype = t2.differencetype;
```

Comment: alright, now here's a twist. is there a way i can use the above script that you provided but limit the update to only update once per categoryid? i have duplicate 'differencetype' of the same kind (eg 'String1' is the differencetype)

Comment: @user1319424: How would you choose which one value to use?

Comment: Anyone would do, but shouldnt be both. I am thinking maybe use the primary key value and select min?